# how to write crawler to crawl data from instagram ?

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, instagram, instagram-api, scrapy

is there any ways crawling / monitoring instagram data for research purpose ?

I tried the official API but it only worked in sandbox which is impossible for crawling the real info like followers. I need to monitor certain accounts and also extend the range by the followers / followings and track their behaviors (e.g. the progress of number of likes)

So anybody can have some suggestions ? or could give me some references about related crawling task ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using beautiful soup library and read this book by Ryan Mitchell: Web Scraping with Python. Basically you should understand the DOM, REGEXs and how to algorithmically jump page to page so that you can get started.

Also do check a site's ToS before you start and know that they may have some guidelines/rules against scraping as generally all sites have [robot.txt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) files these days that specify how/what you're allowed to scrape

Comment: Isn't he looking specifically for instagram ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply !
Specifically for instagram would be perfect but general suggestions would also be appreciated ! :-)
I have experience of crawling websites before but I am not familiar with simulating logging stuff. I think the chapter of advanced part will be helpful.